# deduct current value of table row on total Jquery

Tags: jquery

I wanted to minus the current table row value that was click on total.Currenly I'm getting `Nan`.

This is my current [output](https://jsfiddle.net/rdanalasa/pyqhh45p/46/).

here is my codes for deleting.

```js
function delete_row() {
  var qty = $("input[name*='qty']");
  var piece_type = $("select[name*='piece_type']");
  var total = $("#wpc_total").text();

  qty.each(function(index) {
    var sum = 0;
    var quantity = $(this).val() ? $(this).val() : 0;
    var selected = piece_type.eq(index).find(":selected").text();

    if (selected == documents) {
      price = 10;
      sum = parseFloat(quantity) * parseFloat(price);
    }

    if (selected == small) {
      price = 20;
      sum = parseFloat(quantity) * parseFloat(price);
    }
    total -= sum;
  });
  $("#wpc_total").text("Total : $" + total);
}


$(document).on("click", "input[value='Delete']", delete_row);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: put `console.log` in your loop, and check what is the value of `sum` for each loop, it might be some value not able to parseFloat properly

Comment: @Se0ng11 copy that.

Comment: drill down to `quantity` and `price`, suspect the value not able to parseFloat, if everything is fine, then need to convert `total` to string after calculation finish, need to debug 1 by 1 in order what actually goes wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution would be to reset that values and trigger the change event

```
function delete_row() {
    //Use the current element to context to target parent <TR>
    var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    //Use DOM traversal method to target element
    var elemns = tr.find("select[name*='piece_type'],.number");
    //Reset value and trigger change event
    elemns.val('').trigger('change');
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/etafufvt/)

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  var price = 0;

  var documents = "Documents (Up to 1kg)";
  var small = "Small (1-5kg 85cm)";
  var medium = "Medium (5-10kg 110cm)";

  function checkTotal() {

    var qty = $("input[name*='qty']");
    var piece_type = $("select[name*='piece_type']");
    var total = 0;

    qty.each(function(index) {
      var sum = 0;
      var quantity = $(this).val() ? $(this).val() : 0;
      var selected = piece_type.eq(index).find(":selected").text();

      if (selected == documents) {
        price = 10;
        sum = parseFloat(quantity) * parseFloat(price);
      }

      if (selected == small) {
        price = 20;
        sum = parseFloat(quantity) * parseFloat(price);
      }

      if (selected == medium) {
        price = 30;
        sum = parseFloat(quantity) * parseFloat(price);
      }
      total += sum;
    });
    $("#wpc_total").text("Total : $" + total);
  }

  function delete_row() {
    var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    tr.find("select[name*='piece_type'],.number").val('').eq(0).trigger('change');
  }

  $(document).on("click", "input[value='Delete']", delete_row);
  $("select[name*='piece_type'],.number").change(checkTotal);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wpc_total"></div>

<table>
  <tbody data-repeater-list="pq_package_items">
    <tr data-repeater-item>
      <td>
        <input class="number" type='text' name="qty" required="required" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <select name="piece_type" required="required">
          <option value="">Select Type</option>
          <option value="Documents (Up to 1kg)">Documents (Up to 1kg)</option>
          <option value="Small (1-5kg 85cm)">Small (1-5kg 85cm)</option>
          <option value="Medium (5-10kg 110cm)">Medium (5-10kg 110cm)</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input data-repeater-delete type="button" value="Delete" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-repeater-item>
      <td>
        <input class="number" type='text' name="qty" required="required" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <select name="piece_type" required="required">
          <option value="">Select Type</option>
          <option value="Documents (Up to 1kg)">Documents (Up to 1kg)</option>
          <option value="Small (1-5kg 85cm)">Small (1-5kg 85cm)</option>
          <option value="Medium (5-10kg 110cm)">Medium (5-10kg 110cm)</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input data-repeater-delete type="button" value="Delete" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-repeater-item>
      <td>
        <input class="number" type='text' name="qty" required="required" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <select name="piece_type" required="required">
          <option value="">Select Type</option>
          <option value="Documents (Up to 1kg)">Documents (Up to 1kg)</option>
          <option value="Small (1-5kg 85cm)">Small (1-5kg 85cm)</option>
          <option value="Medium (5-10kg 110cm)">Medium (5-10kg 110cm)</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input data-repeater-delete type="button" value="Delete" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-repeater-item>
      <td>
        <input class="number" type='text' name="qty" required="required" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <select name="piece_type" required="required">
          <option value="">Select Type</option>
          <option value="Documents (Up to 1kg)">Documents (Up to 1kg)</option>
          <option value="Small (1-5kg 85cm)">Small (1-5kg 85cm)</option>
          <option value="Medium (5-10kg 110cm)">Medium (5-10kg 110cm)</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input data-repeater-delete type="button" value="Delete" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to parse an alpha numeric string and hence gets a 'Not a Number'.

```
"Total : $" + total
```

Try storing the total amount in a hidden input field and modify it rather than fetching value from a div tag.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  var price = 0;

  var documents = "Documents (Up to 1kg)";
  var small = "Small (1-5kg 85cm)";
  var medium = "Medium (5-10kg 110cm)";

  function checkTotal() {

    var qty = $("input[name*='qty']");
    var piece_type = $("select[name*='piece_type']");
    var total = 0;

    qty.each(function(index) {
      var sum = 0;
      var quantity = $(this).val() ? $(this).val() : 0;
      var selected = piece_type.eq(index).find(":selected").text();

      if (selected == documents) {
        price = 10;
        sum = parseFloat(quantity) * parseFloat(price);
      }

      if (selected == small) {
        price = 20;
        sum = parseFloat(quantity) * parseFloat(price);
      }

      if (selected == medium) {
        price = 30;
        sum = parseFloat(quantity) * parseFloat(price);
      }

      total += sum;


    });
    $("#wpc-sum").val(total);
    $("#wpc_total").text("Total : $" + total);
  }

  function delete_row() {
    var qty = $("input[name*='qty']");
    var piece_type = $("select[name*='piece_type']");
    var total = $("#wpc-sum").val();

    qty.each(function(index) {
      var sum = 0;
      var quantity = $(this).val() ? $(this).val() : 0;
      var selected = piece_type.eq(index).find(":selected").text();

      if (selected == documents) {
        price = 10;
        sum = parseFloat(quantity) * parseFloat(price);
      }

      if (selected == small) {
        price = 20;
        sum = parseFloat(quantity) * parseFloat(price);
      }
      total -= sum;
    });
    $("#wpc_total").text("Total : $" + total);
  }


  $(document).on("click", "input[value='Delete']", delete_row);
  $("select[name*='piece_type'],.number").change(checkTotal);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wpc_total"></div>
<input type="hidden" id="wpc-sum">
<table>
  <tbody data-repeater-list="pq_package_items">
    <tr data-repeater-item>
      <td>
        <input class="number" type='text' name="qty" required="required" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <select name="piece_type" required="required">
          <option value="">Select Type</option>
          <option value="Documents (Up to 1kg)">Documents (Up to 1kg)</option>
          <option value="Small (1-5kg 85cm)">Small (1-5kg 85cm)</option>
          <option value="Medium (5-10kg 110cm)">Medium (5-10kg 110cm)</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input data-repeater-delete type="button" value="Delete" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-repeater-item>
      <td>
        <input class="number" type='text' name="qty" required="required" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <select name="piece_type" required="required">
          <option value="">Select Type</option>
          <option value="Documents (Up to 1kg)">Documents (Up to 1kg)</option>
          <option value="Small (1-5kg 85cm)">Small (1-5kg 85cm)</option>
          <option value="Medium (5-10kg 110cm)">Medium (5-10kg 110cm)</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input data-repeater-delete type="button" value="Delete" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-repeater-item>
      <td>
        <input class="number" type='text' name="qty" required="required" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <select name="piece_type" required="required">
          <option value="">Select Type</option>
          <option value="Documents (Up to 1kg)">Documents (Up to 1kg)</option>
          <option value="Small (1-5kg 85cm)">Small (1-5kg 85cm)</option>
          <option value="Medium (5-10kg 110cm)">Medium (5-10kg 110cm)</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input data-repeater-delete type="button" value="Delete" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-repeater-item>
      <td>
        <input class="number" type='text' name="qty" required="required" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <select name="piece_type" required="required">
          <option value="">Select Type</option>
          <option value="Documents (Up to 1kg)">Documents (Up to 1kg)</option>
          <option value="Small (1-5kg 85cm)">Small (1-5kg 85cm)</option>
          <option value="Medium (5-10kg 110cm)">Medium (5-10kg 110cm)</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input data-repeater-delete type="button" value="Delete" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```